# logstash run all config files on start/restart

Tags: logstash

I have a question related to starting all the conf files when my linux server restarts automaticallv.

I have 3 conf files in folder /etc/logstash/conf.d/

I want them to start automatically when I start/restart my machine. Is this possible without writing some startup shell script?

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: You shouldn't have to write your own startup script - ones exist for the major platforms.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to my problem is the following command:

**/opt/logstash/bin/logstash agent -f /etc/logstash/conf.d**

website: https://ianunruh.com/2014/05/monitor-everything-part-2.html

Comment: Well... that answers the question "how do I start Logstash and have it read all files in /etc/logstash/conf.d". It doesn't address the "start automatically" question that was posed.